# PostgreSQL Timestamp substraction - want the result in hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Table :

```
create table examp (
  ID   integer,
  val1 timestamp,
  val2 timestamp,
  primary key(ID)
);

insert into examp (ID,val1,val2) values (1,'2011/5/26 10:00:00','2011/5/26 14:00:00');
insert into examp (ID,val1,val2) values (2,'2011/5/26 14:00:00','2011/5/25 14:00:00');
```

Now I want to know the difference of two time stamps in Hours>  I tried:

```
 SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM AGE(val1,val2)) 
   FROM examp 
  WHERE id = 2
```

...but that gives me 0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extracting the hour component, not the number of hours.  Since the timestamp is 24 hours apart, the difference of the hour field is indeed zero.

Presumably you can `extract days * 24 + extract hours` to get the information you want.  As long as it isn't months or years apart...  You could also convert to epoch and then / 3600.

```
select extract(epoch from age(val1,val2))/3600 from examp where id=2;
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i do it so it would give me the difference in number of hours. so for above extraction i want something to give result as 24.